# .NET How to Allow a Windows Form Application to be a Webhook Reciever

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

The current project I'm working on is a Windows Form Application, which in large part functions as a background service to make Queries to a decent number of APIs and store that information into a database. Pretty straightforward.

As I implement more data sources the issue I'm running into is that one of the places I'm pulling from wants to use webhooks to push that data to me. Again fairly straightforward, I did some tutorials on making ASP.NET Web API projects and all of that makes sense in isolation.

Now what I'm confused about is to tie it all together. From my understanding, the options I have would be to have the Form application and the Web API application run separately, which seems like more separation than I want (especially considering that the webhook is for a single item of data that already ties into what the Form application is handling). Alternatively the other option would be to get the Form application to to self host a Web service which seems like the way to go, but I'm unsure of how to approach that without starting with the Web API shell.

I tried reading up on it and [this](https://jonhilton.net/2016/07/18/your-first-net-core-web-application-using-nothing-but-the-command-line/) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/Asp-Net-web-api-self-hosting/) seem to solidify that it would definitely be possible to just host the webhook receiver/controller server inside of the form application without making a new project for it. But I'm not sure of what config, new files and settings of that kind it would take.

I would be super thankful for anyone who could offer guidance about how to go about implementing this webhook controller in a project type not designed for it by default, or if you could tell me that it's a bad idea and I should make separate projects for them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

"Webhooks" (or HTTP callbacks, in general) require a publicly routable address. At home, your desktop computer likely sits behind a NAT and with a dynamic IP address, so it won't work unless you enable port-forwarding and find out your publicly routeable address (assuming it's possible at all and you aren't running inside a restricted company or school/university network). You'll probably want to use AWS Lambda or Azure Functions as a quick and simple way of accepting messages from the public web which your desktop program can retrieve them from later-on (using a "mailbox" paradigm). You could try making it work in real-time with a WebSocket or EventSource but I don't know if that works from AWS Lambda or Azure Functions - if it doesn't then you'll need a "real" website.

Comment: So the computer I'm using is already hosting a website, and it will be capable of doing that, so with that in place I really just need to figure out this logistics of combining the webhook controller into that if you have any advice to offer as to how to go about that.

Comment: Even if you can't do web sockets or event sourcing from those, you could push them into a queue such as Azure Service Bus. This handles the mailbox part automatically, so you wouldn't need to manually store the messages and figure out which have been processed and which haven't.